# Change file extension of several files in one command

Tags: bash, unix, command-line, pipe

I'm using a binary to convert a file type to another:

```
./rcc -binary themes/redTheme.qrc -o redTheme.rcc
```

I have several `.qrc` files and would like to convert them as well, but in the same command. How to regroup them rename and their type? I'm struggling to find a way to keep the file name.

I was thinking about binding my `rcc` binary to a `pipe` that would execute a loop converting the `.qrc` files.

Answer (score 1):

I hope you can bind this with your binary:

```
ls *.qrc | xargs -I {} sh -c 'mv $1 `basename $1 .html`.rcc' - {}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

> $ for i in *.qrc ; do echo mv -v ${i} ${i%.qrc}.new ; done

See here an example where I have a couple of files with `qrc` ending and I `mv` them to `.new`

```
$ l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 1.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 10.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 2.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 3.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 4.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 5.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 6.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 7.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 8.qrc
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 9.qrc
$ for i in *.qrc ; do mv -v ${i} ${i%.qrc}.new ; done
1.qrc -> 1.new
10.qrc -> 10.new
2.qrc -> 2.new
3.qrc -> 3.new
4.qrc -> 4.new
5.qrc -> 5.new
6.qrc -> 6.new
7.qrc -> 7.new
8.qrc -> 8.new
9.qrc -> 9.new
$ l
total 0
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 1.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 10.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 2.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 3.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 4.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 5.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 6.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 7.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 8.new
-rw-r--r--  1 chl  wheel  0 Mar  9 16:22 9.new
$
```

Of course you have to use your `rcc` tool instead of `mv` and use your ending instead of .new

Comment: Please comment if you down vote answers. Especially if they work perfectly fine.